# Display information of particular item the user clicks on the item in html page using jquery and jsp(or php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jsp

So i have a college project in which i am supposed to create movie library.So my main page has many different movies.If i click on any movie poster,it will take me to the a page which will show information of the movie poster i clicked.So my main aim to to create a basic template for movie information like movie director,movie rating,movie actor etc which will change according to the movie poster clicked.All these data will be stored in database.If someone can point me to the right direction,it would be cool!

Comment: What have you tried ? Or are you asking somebody to write your code for you ?

Comment: No idea on how to code this.Wanted to just know the method.

Answer (score 0):

**IF you choose to work with PHP**

I believe that in your case, when the user click the movie info button you'll have to pass an identificator (id_movie or something) via GET or POST. That way you will need one page for displaying the information and populate the description of that movie accordingly to that especific movie ID.

More info on passing variables between pages in php is avaliable [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Put  hyper links to each of the movie posters and pass identifying variables like

```
<a href='phpfile.php?movie=movie1' title='movie name'><img src='movieposterimg.jpg' alt='movie name' width='100' height='100'></a>
```

and in phpfile.php (template) use

```
$moviename=$_GET['movie'];
```

Then pull data from database for that movie.